# Pass array list back to struts jsp using spring controller?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, struts

Working with two projects, one built on struts and one built on spring.  I need to be able to make an ajax call to bring back a list of objects so that I can display them in the html for the struts project.  Currently the ajax call to the controller is working correctly but I'm having trouble passing back the array list.  Any suggestions?

javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sampleUrl.com/controller/call',
    success: function(data) {
        //handle returned object
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = 'call', method = RequestMethod.Get)
public @ResponseBody List<SampleObject> getSampleObjects(HttpServletRequest request) {
     List<SampleObject> sampleList = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
     sampleList.add(new SampleObject());
     return sampleList;
}
```

Comment: change your annotation to indicate the type of request (GET). As it is, the controller method will never be called as it is not mapped to a request type.

Comment: I forgot to add that in my sample code, but I do have it in the actual code I've been running.  I'll update the post to reflect that.

Comment: Is the class annotated to be mapped to `controller` then?

Comment: Yes, the method is getting called just fine.  I have a debug point to make sure when the AJAX call is made it is hitting the method which is every time.  The issue is the data being returned, I'm unable to access the object properties.  The return comes back with a huge list of null data even though the data in the list is a single object with simple text strings for my testing.  I'm think it's an issue with creating a struts readable object when using the spring controller functionality.

Comment: When the code was incorrect, I was led to believe the controller method was not working (which it wouldn't have in the original condition).

Comment: Yep, you were correct.  I spent a couple more hours working on the problem and figured it out.  Posted my answer below but it basically came down to returning a String that was Json formatted so that the jsp javascript file could loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller I had to add produces="application/json" to the @RequestMapping and before the return create a new Gson and return gson.ToJson() of the list.  On my jsp file I it was able to loop through the list normally once the JSON was returned by adding dataType: 'json' to the ajax call.

javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sampleUrl.com/controller/call',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = 'call', method = RequestMethod.Get, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getSampleObjects(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
     List<SampleObject> sampleList = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
     sampleList.add(new SampleObject());
     Gson gson =  new Gson();
     return gson.toJson(sampleList);
}
```